# Wie heißen Berliner in Berlin?

Tags: meaning, regional

Aus gegebenem Anlaß obige Frage. Zu Silvester isst man in einem Teil Deutschlands Berliner; jedoch nicht in Berlin. Wer will kann ja gerne noch folgendes beantworten:

1. Wie heißen Frankfurter in Frankfurt?
2. Wie heißen Hamburger in Hamburg?
3. Wie heißen Wiener in Wien?

Comment: Man isst zu Silvester Krapfen? Das ist mir völlig neu …

Comment: Wie heißen Kameruner in Kamerun, Neapolitaner in Neapel Mars auf dem Mars?

Comment: Die Antworten zeigen mal wieder, wieso es nicht sinnvoll ist, mehrere Fragen auf einmal zu stellen.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: 1. War meine Frage nicht ganz so ernst gemeint, eher als kleines Rätsel, um das Jahr zu beginnen, bin ja positiv überrascht, was das hier ausgelöst hat. ;-) 2. Laut [Stackoverflow](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/18413/german-language) ist es besser, wenn Fragen mehrere Antworten erhalten, ich gebe zu, das ist etwas fragwürdig, aber was tut man nicht alles um eine Statistik zu fälschen. ;-)

Comment: @Thomas: Laut der verlinkten Übersicht werden aber noch dringender *mehr Fragen pro Tag* benötigt als *mehr Antworten pro Frage*. Wobei ich persönlich v.a. letzteres Kriterium für fragwürdig halte auf einem Frage-Antwort-Netzwerk, das darauf abzielt, pro Frage möglichst eine "definitiv richtige" Antwort für die Nachwelt zu ermitteln.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Bei der Statistik kam mir auch in den Sinn, daß die Ratio pro Tag auch etwas zweifelhaft ist, eine gute Seite zeichnet sich auch dadurch aus, daß man aus dem Archiv schlau wird. Aber dieses ganze für und wider ist wohl eher was für Meta.

Comment: @Thomas Es geht nicht darum, mehrere verschiedene Fragen zu stellen, damit mehr Antworten gegeben werden können. Es geht darum, *eine* Frage aus mehreren Blickwinkeln zu beleuchten.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Zum Verbreitungsgebiet von Berliner, Krapfen usw. gibt es (beinahe selbstverständlich) eine Karte im *[Atlas zur deutschen Alltagssprache](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-4/f03/):*

[image: Atlas zur deutschen Alltagssprache]

Demnach heißen Berliner in Berlin Pfannkuchen.

Comment: Daher war auch John F. Kennedys berühmter Satz „Ich bin ein Berliner“ in Berlin vollkommen unmissverständlich.

Comment: Du könntest ggf. noch die Pfannkuchen-Karte mit dazu machen.

Comment: @pH13-YetanotherPhilipp Die entsprechende Karte zu _Pfannkuchen_ wird [hier](http://german.stackexchange.com/a/34005/9551) gezeigt und diskutiert. Mit der Frage „Wie heißen Berliner in Berlin?“ hat diese Karte aber nicht direkt etwas zu tun. Außerdem würde eine Erläuterung in dieser Antwort der anderen [Frage](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/33998/9551) rückwirkend einen Teil der Grundlage entziehen.

Answer (score 11):

Zu 1 und 3 (Wie heißen Frankfurter in Frankfurt? Wie heißen Wiener in Wien?):

Der aus Frankfurt stammende Fleischergeselle Johann Georg Lahner kam vor ziemlich genau 200 Jahren nach Wien. Dort kreierte er Würstel aus Kalb- und Schweinefleisch, groß genug, dass man ein Paar gemeinsam mit einer Semmel als Snack essen konnte.

Diese Wurst wurde in Wien schnell sehr beliebt, und weil sie ein Frankfurter erfunden hat, hieß sie in Wien »Frankfurter Würstel« oder kurz »Frankfurter«.

Als der Geselle seine Lehrjahre in Wien beendet hate, kehrte er nach Frankfurt zurück und nahm das so erfolgreiche Würstel-Rezept mit. Weil er aber die Würstel in Wien erfunden hat, nannte man sie in Frankfurt »Wiener Würstchen«. Unter diesem Namen wurden diese Würstchen dann in ganz Deutschland bekannt, während sich in ganz Österreich der Name »Frankfurter« durchsetzte.

Als dann viele Deutsche nach Amerika auswanderten, nahmen die die Wiener mit in die USA, wo sie auch heute noch »wiener« heiße, obwohl man Wien in den USA als »Vienna« kennt.

Es war übrigens ein Neffe von Lahner, der in die USA auswanderte und dort die *Hot Dogs* erfand.

Zu erwähnen ist noch, dass es auch in Österreich eine Wiener Wurst gibt, die sieht aber so aus:

[image]

Comment: Würstchen ist eben nicht Wurst. Wie heißt denn die mit den Furchen?

Comment: @userunknown: Wurst mit Furchen? Jede getrocknete Wurst wird runzelig falls du das meinst, und z.B. bei Salami ist es üblich, sie genau in diesem Zustand zu verkaufen: http://kingofwallpapers.com/salami/salami-005.jpg Meintest du das?

Comment: Ja, die Furchen stimmen schon sehr gut, aber sie ist innen irgendwie heller. (Wir sollten die Diskussion wohl bald als too chatty wieder löschen).

Answer (score 6):

Berliner heißen in Berlin: Pfannkuchen, die wiederum heißen in Berlin: Eierkuchen.