# Pfannkuchen = Krapfen = Berliner?

Tags: meaning, regional

Bitte klärt mich armen Ösi auf!

In einer [Antwort auf eine andere Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/33995/1487) wurde diese Karte gepostet:

[image]

Dieses Bild legt nahe, dass Pfannkuchen, Berliner und Krapfen dieselbe Süßspeise wäre, die eben nur je nach Region anders genannt wird.

Das widerspricht aber dem was ich bisher über die seltsamen kulinarischen Bezeichnungen in Deutschland gelernt habe. Ich war bis gerade eben der Meinung, dass das, was die Deutschen als »Pfannkuchen« bezeichnen, Palatschinken wären, also so etwas:

[image: Palatschinken]

Weiters dachte ich, dass die Dinger, zu denen Deutsche »Berliner« sagen, Krapfen wären, also etwas, das so aussieht:

[image]

Aber das sind zwei ganz verschiedene Süßspeisen. Es werden zwar beide traditionell gerne mit Marillenmarmelade gefüllt (aber auch mit vielen anderen Leckereien), aber der Teig ist ein ganz anderer. Palatschinken macht man aus einem ziemlich flüssigen [Palatschinkenteig](http://www.ichkoche.at/palatschinkenteig-rezept-214911), Krapfen hingegen aus [Germteig](http://www.gutekueche.at/germteig-grundrezept-artikel-1767), der vor dem Backen einige Zeit ruhen muss, damit er aufgehen kann.

Was haben Pfannkuchen in einer Karte zu suchen, in der es um Synonyme für Krapfen geht?

---

**Glossar**
(für alle, die mit den österreichischen kulinarischen Begriffen wenig vertraut sind):

- die Palatschinke
  ist eine sehr flache Teigspeise. Das Wort leitet sich vom lateinischen »placenta« (Kuchen) ab, wanderte aber zuerst durch Rumänien (»plăcintă«), Ungarn (»palacsinta«) und Böhmen (»palačinka«) bevor es in den österreichischen Wortschatz Einzug hielt.
  Silbentrennung: Pa-la-tschin-ke. Nur die dritte Silbe (tschin) wird betont, alle anderen sind unbetont)
- die Marille
  österreichisches Wort für Aprikose.
- die Marmelade
  wird in Österreich verwendet, um Konfitüren aller Art zu bezeichnen.
- die Germ
  österreichisches Wort für Hefe.

Comment: Was sagt [dein Wörterbuch](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Pfannkuchen)? Siehe auch: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pfannkuchen für eine Liste alternativer regionaler Bezeichnungen.

Comment: @Takkat: Beide Quellen sagen mir zu wenig. Die beiden Antworten, die ich bisher erhalten habe, liefern da schon brauchbarere Informationen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Die in der Frage dargestellte Karte aus dem *[Atlas zur deutschen Alltagssprache](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-4/f03/):* zeigt die Antworten aus dem Zeitraum von Juli 2006 bis Dezember 2007 auf die Frage nach der Bezeichnung im jeweils normalen örtlichen Sprachgebrauch für **„ein rundliches Fettgebäck, das mit feinem Zucker bestäubt oder einer Glasur überzogen ist und mit Marmelade gefüllt ist.“**

[image: Atlas zur deutschen Alltagssprache, 4. Runde, Frage 3]

In einer späteren [Internet-Umfrage](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-7/f01a/) wurde auch einmal nach der Bezeichnung für **„ein rundes, flaches, süßes Gericht aus einem Teig aus Mehl, Milch und Eiern“** gefragt. Für die Antworten aus dem Zeitraum von Dezember 2009 und Dezember 2010 wurde auch eine entsprechende Karte erstellt:

[image: Atlas zur deutschen Alltagssprache, 7. Runde, Frage 1a]

Die Karten spiegeln also hauptsächlich die Interpretation der abstrakten Beschreibungen wider. Die konkret gemeinten regionalen Süßspeisen können daher durchaus etwas voneinander abweichen.

Die zweite Karte bestätigt allerdings die in der Frage genannte Annahme, dass die im größten Teil Österreichs übliche Bezeichnung *Palatschinke* ungefähr der im größten Teil Deutschlands üblichen Bezeichnung *Pfannkuchen* entspricht.

Comment: Dass die Karten die »Interpretation der abstrakten Beschreibungen« widerspiegeln muss nicht so sein. Ich habe an der Umfrage der 10. Runde teilgenommen, wo einige Fragen mit Bildern unterlegt waren, während die anschließende Auswertung versucht hat, den Inhalt der Bilder zu beschreiben. Es wäre also durchaus möglich, dass bei der ursprünglichen Befragung entsprechende Krapfen- beziehungsweise Pfannkuchenbilder (Bereich südwestlich von München zur Zuordnung) vorhanden waren.

Comment: @Jan Ja, daran, dass in diesen Umfragen manchmal Beispielbilder gezeigt werden, habe ich auch schon gedacht. Allerdings könnte es dann trotzdem noch so sein, dass beispielsweise in eine typische österreichische Palatschinke andere Zutaten gehören als in einen typischen westdeutschen Pfannkuchen. Solche regionalen Unterschiede würden also von der Umfrage nicht unbedingt erfasst, weswegen aus der Karte streng genommen nicht zwangsläufig folgt, dass die Süßspeise, die in Österreich _Palatschinke_ heißt, in Westdeutschland _Pfannkuchen_ genannt wird.

Comment: @Jan: Ich glaube Loong hat recht. Ich glaube auch, dass westdeutsche Pfannkuchen und ostösterreichische Palatschinken nicht genau dasselbe sind. Insofern ist die Frage wie Palatschinken in Deutschland heißen, ohnehin unsinnig, weil es Palatschinken, so wie sie z.B. in Wien zubereitet werden, in Deutschland so gut wie gar nicht zu finden sind. Ich habe nämlich den Verdacht, dass Pfannkuchen, die z.B. in Köln hergestellt werden, eher dem ähneln, was man in Osterreich ein Omelett nennen würde. Palatschinken haben eine sehr große Ähnlichkeit mit französischen Crêpes, sind aber nicht genau dasselbe

Answer (score 6):

- Die Karte zeigt regionale Begriffe für "Rundliches Hefegebäck mit (Marmeladen-)Füllung in heißem Fett ausgebacken". Und in manchen Regionen Deutschlands heißen sie eben "Pfannkuchen".
- In den Regionen, die dafür den Begriff "Pfannkuchen" verwenden, wird stattdessen der "Flache Fladen aus flüssigem Eierteig, in der Pfanne ausgebacken und mit Füllung (süß oder salzig) gefaltet oder gerollt" als Eierkuchen o.ä. bezeichnet.
- Und für mich (SW-Deutschland/Schwaben) gibt es einen klaren Unterschied zwischen "Berliner" (= gefüllt) und "Krapfen" bzw. im Februar "Fasnetsküchle" (= ungefüllt).

Warum die Namen so irreführend sind? Ich habe keine präzisen Quellen, aber ich vermute einen ähnlichen Mechanismus wie bei *Wiener / Frankfurter*.

Und: "Pfannen" im etwas altertümlichen Sprachgebrauch  können sowohl die ganz flachen Bratgefäße mit einem Stiel wie für Palatschinken, als auch flache weite Töpfe (kennst Du vielleicht als "Reine"?) sein, die sich für Fettgebäck eignen: damit kann man beide Gerichte zu Recht als "Pfannkuchen" bezeichnen.

Comment: Danke Stephie für die Unterscheidung von Berliner und Krapfen (Füllung), Krapfen werden in Berlin übrigens eher *Kameruner* genannt. ;-)

Comment: @Thomas das habe ich heute aus der Recherche zu den Kommentaren der ursprünglichen Frage auch gelernt. Wie soll man da die Übersicht behalten? ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Ja, das ist durchaus verwirrend, aber es ist tatsächlich so: das, was im Südwesten **Berliner** heisst, wird in anderen Regionen Deutschlands **Krapfen** und eben **Pfannkuchen** genannt.

Um die Verwirrung komplett zu machen gibt es den Begriff **Pfannkuchen** in anderen Regionen für ein anderes Gericht.

Hier bei uns in Freiburg ist ein Pfannkuchen genau das, was Du oben abgebildet hast.
ABER: auch davon gibt es verschiedene Versionen. Es gibt den süssen Pfannkuchen, der mit Puderzucker oder Apfelmuss zubereitet wird. Diesen gibt es wiederum auch in Berlin / Brandenburg, heisst dort aber **Plinze**.

Dann gibt es aber auch noch die deftige Variante: diese wird z.B. Mit Hackfleischsauce oder zu Spargeln mit Sauce Hollandaise gegessen.

Der selbe Teig wird auch für **Kratzede** verwendet, das sind quasi "zerrrissene" Pfannkuchen.

Comment: Palatschinken gibts auch in Österreich mit pikanter oder mit süßer Füllung. Der »zerrissene Pfannkuchen« heißt in Österreich »Kaiserschmarrn« oder einfach nur »Schmarrn« (ohne »e« zwischen »rr« und »n«!). Der Teig ist im Wesentlichen ein Palatschinkenteig dem noch Eischnee (geschlagenes Eiklar) zugegeben wird. http://static.chefkoch-cdn.de/ck.de/rezepte/190/190036/772546-420x280-fix-altbaerlis-kaiserschmarrn.jpg Ach ja: Puderzucker heißt in Österreich »Staubzucker«

Comment: Noch etwas fällt mir dazu ein: In Österreich gibt es zwar keine Plinzen, aber sehr wohl Pinzen, nämlich zu Ostern und in manchen Gegenden (z.B. in St. Pölten, wo ich seit knapp einem Jahr wohne) auch zu Weihnachten: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osterpinze (etymologisch mit den beiden Fladenbroten *Pita* und *Pizza* verwandt, hat aber trotzdem eine annähernd kugelige Form mit drei Zipfeln)

Comment: Bin in Berlin geboren, aber noch nie Plinze oder Kratzede gehört. Will ja nicht anzweifeln, daß es die Begriffe gibt, sind aber u.U. nicht so stark verbreitet. Deshalb würde ich etwas aufpassen, das mit "Pfannkuchen" gleich zu setzen.

Comment: @Thomas "Kratzede" ist Schwäbisch / Badisch, ich denke Torsten bezieht sich auf eine im SW heimische Variante dessen, was man aus flüssigem Mehl-Milch-Ei-Teig machen kann. Zumindest lese ich die Antwort so.

Comment: @Thomas von der brandenburgischen Verwandschaft kenne ich **Plinzen** as Begriff (als Mecklenburger sind es für mich *Eier-* oder *Pfann-* oder *Eierpfannkuchen*, auf der Karte ist die Region als Übergangsgebiet etwas verwirrt). **Kratzede** klingt tatsächlich eher süddeutsch. *Berliner* sind ansonsten auch bekannt.