# Pfannkuchen or Pfannekuchen

Tags: word-usage, etymology

I know them as "Pfannkuchen" and my dictionary says the same, but I have a girl in my class who says "Pfannekuchen" and as far as I know that's completely normal as well.
Now my question (or rather questions) would be:

- Where are either of those words used? (Because I have a feeling that Pfannkuchen is more common in Bavaria and not in the upper parts of Germany.)
- Why is it shortened to "Pfannkuchen"? (A bit weird, I know. But she asked me and I was confused.)

Comment: Related: [Pfannkuchen = Krapfen = Berliner?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/33998/9551)

Comment: Da Du laut Deinem Profil Deutsche bist, darfst Du hier auch gerne auf deutsch fragen. (Bzw. solltest sogar.)

Comment: *Kantapper, Kantapper in den Wald hinein* - Das "Märchen vom Pfannekuchen" verwendet die alte Schreibweise: http://gutenberg.spiegel.de/buch/m-2208/8

Comment: Diese Grafik zeigt gut, wo das Wort gebraucht wird: http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-7/f01a/

Answer (score 3):

Zunächst mal kennt der Duden nur das Wort "Pfannkuchen".

Da es sich um eine Art in der Pfanne gebackene Kuchen handelt, wäre wohl der Herkunft nach das Wort "Pfannenkuchen" das logischste.
Davon kann man sowohl die Variante "Pfannekuchen" als auch "Pfannkuchen" als regionale Verkürzungen ableiten, ähnlich wie man regional das Verb "gehen" zu "gehn" oder "gehe" verkürzt.

Als gebürtiger Sachse würde ich das Wort Pfannkuchen verwenden, meine damit allerdings das was in großen Teilen Deutschlands als Berliner bekannt ist. Die in der Pfanne gebackenen Kuchen heißen bei uns Eierkuchen oder Plinse. Aber das ist ein anderes Thema ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Duden Deutsches Universalwörterbuch, 2. Auflage, 1989, (1819 Seiten) kennt interessanterweise nur *Pfannkuchen*. Dazu gibt diese Duden-Ausgabe noch die mittelhochdeutsche Form *pfankuoche* und die althochdeutsche Form *pfankuocho* sowie folgende Erklärung: "1. in der Pfanne gebackene, flache Mehlspeise aus Eiern, Mehl u. Milch; Eier[pfann]kuchen. 2. in schwimmendem Fett gebackenes, meist mit Marmelade gefülltes, kugelförmiges Gebäckstück aus Hefeteig; Berliner."

*Pfannekuchen* (mit e) kommt in der mündlichen Sprache in einigen Regionen oder sozialen Schichten auch vor, wird in der schriftlichen Kommunikation aber kaum zu finden sein.

As for the question of your class mate why the e is left out, you may answer her that the word has been in use as *Pfannkuchen* or *pfankuocho* for about 1000 years (or at least that's what is documented in writing), so one could question if it was left out at all, or if in *Pfannekuchen* it is rather an addition. But probably she will be confused then.

**Nachtrag:** Grimms Wörterbuch der Deutschen Sprache kennt dagegen (natürlich) mehr Varianten:

> pfannenkuchen, pfannekuchen, pfannkuchen, m.

und führt dazu auf:

> ahd. pfanchuocho, mhd. phankuoche, mnd. pannekoke, holländ. pannekoek, in einer pfanne gebackener kuchen, vgl. pfannendatsch, -fladen, -zelte. pfannkuche [...]

Comment: Ich komm' ja auch hin und wieder durcheinander - Aber deutsch *und* Englisch in einer Antwort hab' ich noch nicht hingekriegt ;)

Comment: Pas de problèmе! Всеки както предпочита!